# Making all categorical variables start at 0 in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame like so where every column is a categorical encoding:

```
> race <- factor(c(0,1,0,1,1))
> income <- factor(c(1,1,1,0,0))
> sex <- factor(c(1,1,1,3,2))
> df <- data.frame(race, income, sex)
> df
  race income  sex
1    0      1    1
2    1      1    1
3    0      1    1
4    1      0    3
5    1      0    2
```

How can I dynamically program in R dplyr so that every column starts at 0.
For example race and income wouldn't be changed because the lowest value is already 0.
But Sex would be need to changed so that every number is subtracted by 1.

expected output:

```
  race income  sex
1    0      1    0
2    1      1    0
3    0      1    0
4    1      0    2
5    1      0    1
```

Ideally the solution would use mutate and across, but I can't seem to get a solution.

Comment: `as.data.frame(
lapply(df, function(x) as.factor(as.numeric(x)-1)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
df %>%
  mutate(
    across(everything(), as.numeric),
    across(everything(), ~.-min(.)),
    across(everything(), as.factor)
  )
)
```

Comment: I'm getting an error here: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`. ℹ `..1 = across(everything(), ~. - min(.))`. x ‘min’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: Ah did not notice you had them as factors. I'll update.

Answer (score 0):

You may change the factor levels to numeric and then subtract 1 from it. Change it back to `factor` if you want to maintain them as categorical.

Use `across` to apply the function to multiple columns.

```
library(dplyr)

relevel_to_0 <- function(x) {
  factor(as.integer(x) - 1)
}

df %>% mutate(across(.fns = relevel_to_0))

#  race income sex
#1    0      1   0
#2    1      1   0
#3    0      1   0
#4    1      0   0
#5    1      0   1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add levels param when you make factor vector

```
race <- factor(c(0,1,0,1,1))
income <- factor(c(1,1,1,0,0))
sex <- factor(c(1,1,1,1,2), levels=0:2)

df <- data.frame(race, income, sex)
df[1,] <- 0
df

#   race income sex
# 1    0      0   0
# 2    1      1   1
# 3    0      1   1
# 4    1      0   1
# 5    1      0   2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following codes:

```
library(tidyverse)

race <- factor(c(0,1,0,1,1))
income <- factor(c(1,1,1,0,0))
sex <- factor(c(1,1,1,3,2))
df <- data.frame(race, income, sex)

> df
  race income sex
1    0      1   1
2    1      1   1
3    0      1   1
4    1      0   3
5    1      0   2

df %>% mutate_if(is.factor, .funs = ~ as.numeric(.)) %>% mutate_if(.predicate = ~ min(.) > 0, .funs = ~ as.factor( . - 1))

  race income sex
1    0      1   0
2    1      1   0
3    0      1   0
4    1      0   2
5    1      0   1
```

or combine two `mutate_if` functions in one:

```
df  %>% mutate_if(.predicate = ~ (is.factor(.) & min(as.numeric(.)) > 0) , .funs = ~ as.factor( as.numeric(.) - 1))

  race income sex
1    0      1   0
2    1      1   0
3    0      1   0
4    1      0   2
5    1      0   1
```